# How to create an index on a large list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-threshold, index, large-lists

I am using SharePoint Online and have a large list exceeding 50K items. When attempting to create an index I receive the error that the list exceeds the list view threshold. The solution to this appears to be creating the index during the 'Daily Time Window', which I cannot access in SharePoint Online b/c MSFT hides the 'Manage Web Applications' tool.

Is there a Daily Time Window for SP Online? If not, how can you create an index on a large list otherwise? Does anyone have experience with this issue in SP Online specifically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no happy hour. At this point in time, your only option is to delete 45,000 items, create your index, and restore the 45,000 items or create a new list and move the items into it.

They are currently working on large list improvements. It isn't clear what those will be, but until they are announced, the current realistic architectural limit on lists and libraries is 5,000 items. Once you are beyond that, you are basically done for.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/16487710-prioritize-large-list-management-in-sharepoint-onl

Comment: Thanks for your answer - very appreciated. I guess I'll have to get my list below 5000, create my index and reupload. Thanks again.

Comment: still unbelievable how poorly Microsoft products behaves sometimes. Just think of deleting & restoring only because you need a new index field: in productive environments simply an impossible szenario.

Comment: Predictive indexing is supposed to be helpful in this regard, but I've heard mixed experiences with this

Answer (score 0):

On SharePoint Online you can now create new Indexes up to 20,000 items, rather than what was previously 5,000. Additionally, there is an "Auto-Indexer" that will create indexes on Lists/Libraries automatically based on the views that have been created.

Comment: The 20k limit is news to me. Do you have a link to back this up?

Comment: News to me too but it makes sense because I was actually able to reduce my list size to about 12,000 and create an index. I'm still struggling with list views but at least the index was created.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1 "Fortunately, there are two quick actions you can take to fix a blocking issue and free yourself from this catch-22 situation. You can:

Create an index in a list that has up to 20,000 items.

Delete a folder or list (or web site) that contains up to 100,000 items.

Furthermore, there are several additional strategies you can use to either prevent blocking or to fix the blocking issue if you get stuck."

Answer (score 0):

Latest news was that the throttle on listitems was gone with the new OneDrive implementation.

you can index up to 20 columns but only way to do it is bring it back to 5000 items and add the index. tools like ShareGate or other 3rd party apps would help you if you are using production data.

kr,

Paul