# Unable to filter multiple columns of "Person or Group"

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter, person-or-group

I am trying to create a view for our agents so that they can see if they created an item or if they have been added to an item. To do this I thought it would be as simple as:

```
Agent Name (Indexed) 
is equal to
[Me]

OR

Lead originator (Indexed) 
is equal to
[Me]
```

However when I do this  it returns everything (I am assuming this as its goes over 5000 record when the totals for a single agent doesn't go over 1000).

Both columns are a "Person or Group" type. It will work if I only use one of the columns, this only fails when I use both columns

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the case that your indices were not created correctly. If you had more than 5k items in the list the index creation will fail. you need to create new list create indices and migrate content from the other list.

Comment: Do you know of a resource that explains how to do this?

Comment: There is no easy way to do it. I would recommend some migration software like Sharegate, using it at the moment and it is quite stable migrator. According to some you can create indices up to 20k items now. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207367/how-to-create-an-index-on-a-large-list-in-sharepoint-online